# What is the meaning of "Punctual Focus"?

Tags: waves, acoustics

In terms of waves, what is the meaning of punctual focus? For example: a punctual focus is emanating sound waves... I dont know in this context what the word "punctual" means. I only know that if I saw that there is a punctual focus emanating waves, that waves are spherical, but I dont know anything else. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It means that it's always on time to its appointments.

Answer (score 2):

A point source is a source with dimensions are not relevant (for example much smaller than the wavelength or pixel size). It could be a real source, or a pinhole, or a pinhole or diaphragm on which light is focused. And that diaphragm can be left out. Light focused to a point.

A point source can be very large. It can be a star, for example. Then its size is very small when compared to the distance.

Comment: From what you said, I understand that punctual focus is a point source whose dimensions are irrelevant? And if so, what this has to do with spherical waves? That's the part I dont get it

Comment: A point source radiates waves in all directions, with spherical wavefronts.

Comment: Yeah, but there are problems that says: A focus is emanating plane waves... how do you explain that? Haha I want to understand the concept 100%

Comment: @victor26567 At a great distance, the waves from a point source can be plane waves to good approximation.  For example the light from a star.

Comment: Ahh, I see. And the last but not the least. Why we consider the point source with a very little dimensions? why of that?